Лишь спустившись запятая
Ричард говорил, что лишь спустившись к «Титанику», понял, что такое опасность стихии.
Нужна ли запятая перед "лишь"?
Если не нужна, то зачем она перед "понял"?

Ричард говорил, что лишь спустившись к «Титанику», понял, что такое опасность стихии.
Пояснение

Это СПП с двумя придаточными изъяснительными, последовательное подчинение, союз ЧТО.

Деепричастный оборот стоит в начале  первого придаточного, а перед ним находится изъяснительный союз ЧТО, относящийся ко всему придаточному (поэтому нет запятой).

Запятая перед понял ставится в конце оборота. Придаточная часть: лишь спустившись к «Титанику», понял...


